# How to get a specific DocumentSnapshot from List <DocumentSnapshot>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I get querySnapshot of a collection with Firestore and get List .
To get a specific item in a List, it"s necessary to put the number in [], but I want to get a DocumentSnapshot for a specific DocumentId. Is there any way?

I tried indexOf, but it returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
snapshot.documents.firstWhere((doc) => doc.documentID == 'id', orElse: () => null)
```